# What happens after a page fault?

Tags: memory, interrupts

When a page fault occurs in a Linux system, the interrupt-handler has to figure out the reason why the page fault happened. But how ?

- Is there anywhere a special number for that !? If yes, where is that number logged ?
- Is it possible to know the reason for the page-fault before raising the exception ? 
  Eg.

  - **Step-1** 
    Look for the reason by the CPU
  - **Step-2** 
    raise the exception

Comment: What architecture are you asking about?

Comment: I don't understand part 2, "Is it possible to do that page-fault-causing-lookup with the Intel-CPU, before the Intel-CPU raises the exception ?" Are you asking if it is possible to 'get in between' (i.e. take control of the CPU) the actual memory access and the exception being raised? Or are you asking is it possible to detect, without doing the page-fault-causing-lookup that it will cause a page fault? Or something else?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on the Linux site

Comment: @Scott Seidmann: flagging it for migration is a better option then